# How to flag consecutive occurrences across dates in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data is structured as follows in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
    DATE        NAME   SIGN
0   2/24/2010   ABC     1
1   2/24/2010   DEF    -1
2   2/25/2010   ABC     1
3   2/25/2010   GHI    -1
4   2/26/2010   ABC    -1
…
```

I would like to create an additional column that is boolean and indicates whether or not a NAME is present on the following DATE in the data set (i.e. on two consecutive observation DATEs). The dates in the overall data set may not be contiguous.

Additionally, I would like to create a column that is also boolean and indicates whether or note a NAME and like SIGN combination was present on the following DATE in the data set. The resulting DataFrame would look something like this:

```
    DATE        NAME    SIGN    CONS    CONS_SAME_SIGN
0   2/24/2010   ABC     1       TRUE    TRUE
1   2/24/2010   DEF    -1       FALSE   FALSE
2   2/25/2010   ABC     1       TRUE    FALSE
3   2/25/2010   GHI    -1       FALSE   FALSE
4   2/26/2010   ABC    -1       TRUE    FALSE
…
```

I struggled with this problem for several hours to little avail. Ultimately, I wound up writing a nested for loop and solved the problem iteratively. Unfortunately, that solution is painfully slow and I'd much prefer something that utilizes nice features in Pandas such as groupby or apply.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For `'CONS'` columns the following would work: `df['CONS'] = df['DATE'] == df['DATE'].shift(-1)` but I don't understand your second requirement, you asking for a column to indicate whether the `NAME` and `SIGN` match on the following date, so you are wanting to compare by date value rather than subsequent row?